# Why is there no midpoint between "do_GET" and full-blown rails-style routing?

Tags: web-services, jsonp, dispatcher, application-server, thrift

I'm looking to expose a number of services to the web. There will be static web pages with jQuery based JavaScript code that accesses these services, and there will also be all kinds of applications that may access these services. (Or nobody will care; that's also quite possible :-)

Each service would be well defined as a collection of methods that act on some number of input parameters, and return some number of output parameters. Most of it is REST, except for the concept of "identity" -- these services requires some log-in, and logging in does set you up with permissions on which methods on which services you're allowed to use, and what particular entities you're allowed to address using those methods.

Ideally, I want to expose the services using JSONP to make the services easy to consume in a cross-site way -- those static web applications shouldn't all have to be be served from the domain of my application servers.

The set of data types is fairly basic -- varchar (255 chars), text (8191 chars), id (32 chars, C-style identifier constraint), double, long (hard to do in JavaScript), bool, datetime, email (varchar matching a reges) and url (varchar matching a regex) would probably suffice for a very long time.

I want, if possible, to implement these services using an application service technology that can scale on multi-threaded cores -- 24 threads is standard on plain mid-range servers these days. Sticking with Python or Node.js would make me uneasy, because of their lack of threading support. Also, I would like for typing to be static, because I believe static typing prevents a certain class of bugs, which also talks against Python, Node.js, PHP and Ruby.

I also want to serve on Linux. That's a pretty hard requirement :-)

In the static language world, there are really only a few server frameworks or framework approaches. There's HttpListener with Mono. There's Jetty with Java. There's a few others. There are also a few much deeper frameworks, that have more overhead than I'd like -- J2EE, ASP.NET, etc. (In the dynamic world, you have Cake.PHP, Rails, Django, etc etc)

So, in the best of worlds, I'd like the GET URL /foo/bar?arg1=2&arg2=xyzzy to map to an object that I write of type foo, method bar, taking arguments arg1 and arg2 of type int and string (say). I want the server glue that sits between the HTTP GET and the object method to do two things:
1) Permission control (each method could have one or more required permissions)
2) Type checking (each argument should be verified against expected and coerced from the URL string format to the native typ)
Once the method returns one or more values (key/value pairs), the glue should make sure that the return values are also according to spec, convert to proper JSON, and should take care of returning an appropriate error result if an exception was thrown within the code.

I've been looking high and low for this kind of solution, but all solutions I find are pretty far off. JSP and ASP all start out with a HTML assumption -- I'm generally generating JSON, which doesn't integrate as well with the syntax (to put it mildly). JSPX, as well as a number of other technologies (HttpListener, CGI, Python Twisted, ...) all stop at the "do_GET" level -- no dispatch into objects, no permission control, no type checking. All the higher-level frameworks, however, add a *lot* more on top of that, and often adds complex routing that's not something I need -- and as often as not, still don't do permission checking, but instead leaves that as something you have to write manually in each function implementation.

I think the closest I could find to what I want is Thrift. However, it still doesn't do permission checking, and the "PHP server" support it has seems to be a dumb PHP cli process listening on port 80 instead of integrating with Apache, and it's not set up to support JSONP.

Have I missed something? Is there some (preferrably statically typed and multi-thread-supporting) server technology that will do type checking and permission checking and simple object-method dispatch, without tons of other cruft to get in the way, and can be called from (and respond to) JSONP?
Should I extend Thrift? Adding permission constraints on each method would be a fairly substantial extension, but at least I'd get the other support that Thrift has. (And then I'd have to add JSONP support, and ...)

Comment: Btw: this is a follow-up question to the closed wide-reaching technology question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372305/web-framework-shoot-out-closed
If anyone knows of another good place to ask and discuss this question while reaching many different kinds of expertise, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some (preferrably statically typed and multi-thread-supporting) server technology that will do type checking and permission checking and simple object-method dispatch, without tons of other cruft to get in the way

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) (static, actors for threading/concurrency & dispatch, no cruft) + Thrift.

I believe the latest thrift has javascript support (not sure about JSONP).

As for authentication, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621715).

Comment: So that does routing and type checking, but it still doesn't do authentication or validation or access control, leaving those bits to the developer to get wrong. Thanks for the suggestion, but as my question already says Thrift isn't good enough, the language doesn't really matter. (Btw: another great actor environment for REST web apps is Erlang / WebMachine, and Thrift can generate Erlang glue, but again -- Thrift not good enough)

Answer (score 0):

There really doesn't exist any good framework at the right level for this. Existing frameworks are either too low level (think boost::asio), or too high level (think cake, rails, etc). The closest option is probably Erlang/WebMachine. I guess the reason for this is that most web apps end up having a common set of higher-level requirements that then end up migrating into whatever the web framework is, thus lifting it out of the level where I'm looking to go.